# Filtering empty elements in a nested list in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering, nested-lists

I have a list inside a pandas dataframe and I want to filter it. For example, I have a dataframe like this:

```
{
    "examples": [
 
        {
            "website": "info",
            "df": [
                {
                    "Question": "What?",
                    "Answers": []
                },
                {
                    "Question": "how?",
                    "Answers": []
                },
                {
                    "Question": "Why?",
                    "Answers": []
                }
            ],
            "whitelisted_url": true,
            "exResponse": {
                "pb_sentence": "",
                "solution_sentence": "",
                "why_sentence": ""
            }
        },            
         {
            "website": "info2",
            "df": [
                {
                    "Question": "What?",
                    "Answers": ["example answer1"]
                },
                {
                    "Question": "how?",
                    "Answers": ["example answer1"]
                },
                {
                    "Question": "Why?",
                    "Answers": []
                }
            ],
            "whitelisted_url": true,
            "exResponse": {
                "pb_sentence": "",
            }
        },

    ]
}
```

my filter function:

```
def filter(data, name):
   resp = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data),
                         pd.json_normalize(data['examples'])],
                        axis=1)

    resp = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(resp),
                         pd.json_normalize(resp['df'])],
                        axis=1)

    resp['exResponse.pb_sentence'].replace(
        '', np.nan, inplace=True)
    resp.dropna(
        subset=['exResponse.pb_sentence'], inplace=True)
    

    resp.drop(resp[resp['df.Answers'].apply(len) == 0].index, inplace=True)
```

I want to remove the empty 'answers' elements in this dataframe. I have already filtered the empty 'problem_summary' elements using the following code:

```
    resp['exResponse.pb_sentence'].replace(
        '', np.nan, inplace=True)
    resp.dropna(
        subset=['exResponse.pb_sentence'], inplace=True)
```

How can I do the same for the 'answers' elements?

I don't actually expect a specific output. the following part of my code
It throws the error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'". I think this is due to empty answers arrays, so I want to remove these parts.

```
 resp.rename(
        columns={0: 'Challenge', 1: 'Solution', 2: 'Importance'}, inplace=True)
    # challenge deserializing
    resp = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df_resp),
                         pd.json_normalize(resp['Challenge'])],
                        axis=1)
    resp = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(resp),
                         pd.json_normalize(resp['Answers'])],
                        axis=1)
```

error line:

```
     29 resp = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(resp),
---> 30                      pd.json_normalize(resp['Answers'])],
     31                     axis=1)
```

Comment: Can you post your expected output ?

Comment: I've updated my question to respond to your request. Thanks @Psidom

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding based on the sample data you will end up with an empty dataframe?

```
df = pd.json_normalize(
    data=data["examples"],
    meta=["website", "whitelisted_url", "exResponse"],
    record_path=["df"]
)
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop("exResponse").tolist()))
df = df[df["Answers"].map(lambda d: len(d)) > 0]
df = df.replace("", np.nan).dropna(subset=["pb_sentence"], how="all")
```

Comment: I edited my question and explained why I want to remove empty Answers arrays. I would be glad if you could review it again. Thanks.